# Re-schedule the speific trigger of quartz job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I got stuck in one problem about quartz schedular. Actually, the requirement is we have to schedule the job like monthly, half yearly and yearly. Now, the twist is we have to change the trigger time if the trigger time on any job falls on Holiday. So there are two thing, first we can schedule the job on next day and the other one to schedule on the job on previous day. I didn't find anything which can help me on this.

If my requirement is only to schdeule the job after the trigger day then it is pretty simple to write logic on the job itself. But we need to satisfy the previous day condition as well.

It would be great for me if anyone can help on this.